# Confused by PHP session problem (Rackspace)

Tags: php, session, session-variables, rackspace

My PHP session fluctuates between different values for no apparent reason.  here is my test code that proves it:

```
<?php
//test.php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

When I refresh that test.php, the `$_SESSION` has different values (about 3 different arrays in total), as if I was browsing the site in between refreshing the page (I'm not).

Echo'ing `session_id()` doesn't output anything.

Any ideas?  This is completely messing up my handling of sessions/authentication throughout my site.

**Update**: I'm using RackSpace Cloud Sites for hosting

Comment: Are you setting any values like at all in the session?

Comment: Yes, the session returns various arrays you'd run into as if you were using the site-- the array of logged in user data.. array storing values for page redirection etc.  It's a hodgepodge of actual values you'd see using the site

Comment: Are you working from a cluster? Either a clustered DB in the case of DB-saved sessions or a web cluster for file saved sessions?

Comment: What are the different values of $_SESSION that you're seeing?

Comment: @Joseph: I'm hosted by Rackspace Cloud Sites.  Not sure if that answers your question.

@Mike: I'm seeing different arrays that you'd have while using the site, e.g. the array of user data, or sometimes a shorter array containing just which page they're on.

Comment: I've pastebinned the 3 arrays:

http://pastebin.com/zAk1ajHY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rackspace requires a different PHP session handler: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/php-sessions-state-servers-on-cloud-sites-and-how-to-fix-non-working-php-sessions

Comment: Previous link is page not found. New working link is:
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/php-sessions-state-servers-on-cloud-sites-and-how-to-fix-non-working-php-sessions