# PHP sessions not working with Rackspace Cloud

Tags: php, session, rackspace

I'm currently hosting with Rackspace and have multiple cloud servers. On the main domain, I have a wordpress installation that uses PHP sessions for certain advertisement things.

It has a plugin that also helps sessions along in wordpress. On a subdomain (on the same server), I have a login system that also relies on sessions. It doesn't seem to establish a session at all even when I look in the inspector.

The `php.ini's` main directory for sessions is `/tmp`, but for this subdomain I have an `htaccess` that directs it to `/mnt/subfolder/subfolder/` etc. I'm not getting any errors at all, even with errors reporting on.

I have the owner/group set to `root:www-data`, and the permissions of every folder are 777 (except for the main `/mnt` directory, but everything that falls under it is 777).

**Any ideas why sessions just don't work?**

I even tried a small 2 page test to start a session. I don't believe it is a code error because it works on other servers. Also, I don't store sessions from the subdomain in `/tmp` because it seems to interfere with the plugin and subsequently breaks the sessions I'm using on my wordpress site on the main domain.

Comment: Double-enter = paragraph-break `:)`. If you can take care to ask questions like Chris' edits above, it'll save us lots of work. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confused by PHP session problem (Rackspace)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432235/confused-by-php-session-problem-rackspace)

Comment: Also Chris, I looked into that. Didn't fix anything with this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I just read the comments on the rackspace site about it.  I don't think this is something SO is going to be able to solve for you..but I could be wrong.  Retracting my dupe vote though.

Comment: Subdomains use do not share cookies unless you force. Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348282/php-cookie-domain-subdomain-control

Comment: Sadly the subdomain idea didn't work either. I'm not necessarily wanting to even share sessions between both the subdomain and main domain. Sessions are completely non-existent on the subdomain.